# django thumbnails

Tags: django

i tried creating thumbnails of non rectangular images(ie circles) using django thumbs.  It seems the opacity around the circle is not preserved.  Any ideas on what thumbnail tool can preserve that transparency on non-rectangular shapes?

Thanks!

Comment: What were your input and output formats?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[easy_thumbnails](http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/tree/master/easy_thumbnails/) should preserve the Alpha Layer.

(At least it [checks transparency](http://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/blob/master/easy_thumbnails/files.py#L410))